# navbar-toggle disappears at 768px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

for some reason my nav bar toggle disappears at 768px. I am not totally sure what the problem is but I think it has to do with my CSS and media queries. I will post my nav bar code and css for my query at 768px (my media query is like this @media screen and (max-width: 768px) so it should include 768 right?), but I will also include a jsfiddle link with all my code for that page to see if the problem is else where. here is my nav bar code

```
<nav class ="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="navBarStyle" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button data-toggle="collapse-side" data-target=".side-collapse" data-target-2=".side-collapse-container" type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-right">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index2.html"><i>Marvin</i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="side-collapse in">
            <nav role="navigation" class="navbar-collapse ">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                    <a href="html/about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="html/projects.html">Projects</a>
                    </li> 
                    <li>
                    <a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
{

    .side-collapse-container
    {
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        right:0;
        transition:left .4s;
    }

    .side-collapse-container.out
    {
        right:200px;
    }

    .side-collapse
    {
        top:50px;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        width:200px;
        position:fixed;
        overflow:hidden;
        transition:width .4s;
    }

    .side-collapse.in
    {
        width:0;
    }

    #navBarStyle
    {
        margin-top:.5%;
    }


}
```

Not totally sure what the problem is, I read it might be a problem with bootstrap itself. Here is my jsfid https://jsfiddle.net/marvstah/tLzorkdg/1/

IMPORTANT, it works fine on all sizes less the 768 but not on 768

Comment: can you share a fiddle of your code

Comment: Why have you been changing some of the targets and classes? have you tried creating a simple example, using the Bootstrap example, and seeing if that does the same? If it doesn't, the problem isn't Bootstrap.

Comment: In your button you're using `collapse-side`, but then in your div that collapse, that's called `side-collapse`. Is this a typo? Also, you have no `side-collapse-container` in your markup, and you have two `data-targets` in your button, is this allowed? This is very much modified from the Bootstrap example.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `media-query` max-width to `767px`.

Since you are using `bootstrap`. Botstrap.css has some media-query on `767px`. it overwriting yours.

Here is the working **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tLzorkdg/2/)**

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
{

    .side-collapse-container
    {
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        right:0;
        transition:left .4s;
    }

    .side-collapse-container.out
    {
        right:200px;
    }

    .side-collapse
    {
        top:50px;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        width:200px;
        position:fixed;
        overflow:hidden;
        transition:width .4s;
    }

    .side-collapse.in
    {
        width:0;
    }

    #navBarStyle
    {
        margin-top:.5%;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi there, I tried that solution but it did not work on my code, rather, I had to go create a custom boostrap min file with a break point at 767px rather the 768px, but even then this only half works. There is now a vertical white line about 1px in width on the very right of my site and my home page will collapse at 768px but every other page will not.

Comment: Then for your media-query properties give `!important` at the end. It will overwrite bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

just curious, did it ever get solved for you? I am experiencing same issue but on 767px. My viewport works fine on 767px and 768px, but breaks horribly on 767px. 
To my observation, however, max-width: 767px does not include 767px. but on min-width / max-width: 768px both includes 768px! I am pulling my hair...

Comment: Not really. I had a work around. This was years ago so the details are a little fuzzy. I recall going to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/ and adjusting the break points. Sorry, I hope this helps a bit

Answer (score -1):

We need not use all that styling. Anyways we have bootstrap in, so we can use a basic Bootstrap Nav rit?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Marvin</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: my nav bar is for a side collapse, its a little different then this.

Comment: This doesn't address 767 or 768